# Звуковая схема к слову "коньки"

Tags: фонетика

Как обозначается мягкий знак в звуковой схеме?

Answer (score 2):

Мягкий знак в фонетике сам по себе не обозначается в транскрипции. Обозначается апострофом только мягкость того согласного, после которого стоит мягкий знак. Допустим, *галька* [гал'ка], *июль* [ий'ул']. Так же и с "коньками": *коньки* [кан'к'и] (для пущей надёжности можно ещё справа над звуком [а] призвук "о" маленькой буковкой приписать, так как звук [а], здесь, мне кажется, нечётко звучит).